# Failed getting Image width from its onload function using Promise in TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

I use the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

  const imageString = 'https://glebekitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/neapolitanpepperoni.jpg';

  function getPromise(imageData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const myImage = new Image();
        myImage.onload = () => resolve(myImage.width);
        myImage.onerror = reject(-1);
        myImage.src = imageData; 
      });
  }

  async function getWidth() {
    const promise = await getPromise(imageString);
    promise.then(width => {
        return width;
      }).catch(ex => {
            return -1;
      });
  }
  
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> { 
  render() {
    const a = getWidth(); 
    debugger;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {a};
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

(Also loaded it to: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a7ugfq?file=index.tsx )

While expecting to get the width using the getWidth function - I only get the promise with the width as its PromiseResult
What am I doing wrong? how do I get a specific value and not an object when using the above promise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are lots of things wrong in your code. See this [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r4zwet?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

The `getWidth` has a problem. You're awaiting the result from `getPromise`. This means that the result from that function is no longer a Promise, but the value that is returned in the resolve statement. Therefor the `then` and `catch` methods won't work. Instead, just return result from `getPromise`

```
async function getWidth() {
  return getPromise(imageString);
}
```

Don't use side effect operations inside of the `render` method. This method should do one thing, use the available data to render the HTML, but not do any calculations or getting data from async functions.

For this you have the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method that runs whenever the component is rendered for the first time.

In this method, call the `getWidth` function and get the width of the image from it. From here you should update a state which will let the component know that its data has been changed and the component should be rerendered.

```
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imageWidth: null // Set a initial state of null.
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getWidth().then(width => {
      this.setState({
        imageWidth: width
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const imageWidth = this.state.imageWidth;
    
    // If the width is not yet set, render nothing.
    if (imageWidth === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {a};
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `try-catch` block in `getWidth` function is unnecessary; error handling code should be in the calling code. Not to mention that returning the error from the `catch` block will implicitly convert promise rejection into promise fulfilment, leading to the invocation of the fulfilment handler in the calling code. You could re-write `getWidth` function in just one line: `return getPromise(imageString);`

Comment: @Yousaf, I didn't know for sure that was the case. Thanks for clearing that up. Modified the answer.

Comment: Just in case if you are interested in more details, see: [implicit conversion of promise rejection into promise fulfilment](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/common-promise-anti-patterns#converting-promise-rejection-in-to-fulfilment)

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous, so you have to "wait" for them. There are 2 ways.

1. Wait for the result using an async render function
2. Wait for the promise, set the variable as state, and let React re-render the component.

Using an async render function

```
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> { 
  async render() {
    const a = await getWidth(); 
    debugger;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {a};
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using state. Beware, there's a downside.

```
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> { 
  
  render() {
    const [a, setA] = useState(null);
    getWidth().then(width => setA(width)); 
    debugger;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {a};
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The "downside" using this state method, is that the first time the component is rendered, the component uses `null` as the value of `a`.
The best thing about this, is your application renders even if the values of your async methods are not there yet. You could add some `loading` feature, or you could `return null` to tell React you don't want to render this component at all.